# SQL Server ROUND() not working for FLOAT ending in 1

Tags: sql, rounding

I changed my example to use FLOAT's ... too many people were getting hung up on the whole NVARCHAR thing.  We are not storing numbers in the database as NVARCHAR.  I was just using NVARCHAR as an example.  I get the same results with FLOAT.

We're having issues with the SQL Server ROUND() for some FLOAT's

```
    DECLARE @EXCHANGE_RATE FLOAT
    SET @EXCHANGE_RATE = 1.327810000000000000000
    SELECT ROUND(@EXCHANGE_RATE,6,1)
    SET @EXCHANGE_RATE = 1.327820000000000000000
    SELECT ROUND(@EXCHANGE_RATE,6,1)
```

First one returns : 1.327809
Second one returns: 1.32782

You would think the first one would return 1.32781, and not 1.327809.

Is this a feature or bug in the ROUND?  Any easy way around it?

Thanks!

Based on Mat's idea of casting them as DECIMAL, this works ... it's ugly, but works.  The reason I use 10, is I looked in our database, and that seems to be the longest number we store.  Also I need to convert it back to FLOAT because they don't want to see any trailing 0's

```
    DECLARE @EXCHANGE_RATE FLOAT
    SET @EXCHANGE_RATE = 1.327810000000000000000
    SELECT CAST(ROUND(CAST(@EXCHANGE_RATE AS DECIMAL(28,10)),6,1) AS FLOAT)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this query.

```
SELECT
  ROUND('1.3278100',6,0)                     AS x0,
  ROUND('1.3278200',6,0)                     AS y0,
  ROUND('1.3278100',6,1)                     AS x1,
  ROUND('1.3278200',6,1)                     AS y1,

  ROUND(CAST( '1.3278100' AS FLOAT), 6, 0)   AS a0,
  ROUND(CAST( '1.3278200' AS FLOAT), 6, 0)   AS b0,
  ROUND(CAST( '1.3278100' AS FLOAT), 6, 1)   AS a1,
  ROUND(CAST( '1.3278200' AS FLOAT), 6, 1)   AS b1,

  ROUND(CAST( '1.3278100' AS DECIMAL(9,8)), 6, 0)   AS i0,
  ROUND(CAST( '1.3278200' AS DECIMAL(9,8)), 6, 0)   AS j0,
  ROUND(CAST( '1.3278100' AS DECIMAL(9,8)), 6, 1)   AS i1,
  ROUND(CAST( '1.3278200' AS DECIMAL(9,8)), 6, 1)   AS j1
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15607

What this indicates to me is that `ROUND()` is implicitly casting your `VARCHAR` values to `FLOAT` before truncating them.

And as FLOATs can't accurately represent 1.327810, you're actually truncating 1.3278099999999 (or something similar).

So, in short, explicitly cast them to DECIMAL before you truncate.  Or simply don't store numeric data as strings...

Comment: I tried that, but I get trailing 0's when casting to DECIMAL.  I'd then have to try to get rid of them ... if I have to, then that's what I'll have to do.  All the values in the database are stored as FLOAT's, but I get the same behavior with NVARCHAR, that's why I used it as an example.

Comment: When I look at the value in the database, it's a FLOAT and it is 1.32781.  When I select it from the database, it's 1.32781.  When I try to use it in the ROUND(), M$ thinks it's 1.327809999999999999.

Comment: This works ... it's ugly, but works
<pre>
SELECT CAST(ROUND(CAST(@MY_FLOAT AS DECIMAL(18,8)),6,1) AS FLOAT)
</pre>

Comment: @kschlege - I'm not convinced that FLOAT is the correct data type for your needs.  Money, exchange rates, and other values where absolute accuracy are required are traditionally represented using DECIMAL.  It's not M$ that `thinks it's 1.327809999999999999`, that's how floats work, they're binary *approximations*, they are not precise decimal values.  Just as decimal numbers can't accurately represent `1/3`, neither can binary-floating-point numbers represent all decimal values.  There's a lot on the web about it, and you're banging into all the problems of float point errors.  Use DECIMAL.

Comment: Yeah, don't ask me why FLOAT was chosen, that was way before me ... this is all legacy stuff.  Too late now.  I've never used FLOAT, always DECIMAL.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the below here for the moment, it is true, but it is not the reason for the op's issue.
The correct answer is the one provided by MatBailie, -the nVarChar string is being converted to a float, and then the truncation operation is reducing it to the next lower value...

From MSDN for [Round function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

function
Is the type of operation to perform. function must be tinyint, smallint, or int. When function is omitted or has a value of 0 (default), numeric_expression is rounded. ***When a value other than 0 is specified, numeric_expression is truncated.***

try this, it shows the difference:

```
DECLARE @EXCHANGE_RATE NVARCHAR(200)
SET @EXCHANGE_RATE = '1.3278100'
SELECT ROUND(@EXCHANGE_RATE,6,0) Rounded,
       ROUND(@EXCHANGE_RATE,6,1) Truncated

SET @EXCHANGE_RATE = '1.327810000001'
SELECT ROUND(@EXCHANGE_RATE,6,0) Rounded,
       ROUND(@EXCHANGE_RATE,6,1) Truncated
```

the output type is determined by the input... In this case, the input is '1.3278100', so the value is cast to a numeric datatype, with a precision based on the number of significant digits in the string ('1.3278100' has 5 significant digits) so the output type is determined to be numeric(6,5) or something like that... this causes the unexpected truncation. This has bitten me before.

Comment: So 1.3278100 truncated is 1.327809?  That doesn't seem right to me ... it's like saying 100 is the same as 90.

Comment: I'm getting 1.327809, same as they say they are getting for first example

Comment: Yes, because the output type is determined by the input... In this case, the input is '1.3278100', the value is cast to a numeric datatype, with a precision based on the number of significant digits in the string ('1.3278100' has 5 significant digits) so the output type is determined to be numeric(6,5) or something like that

Comment: Then why don't I get 1.327819 when Rounding the 1.32782?  The only thing I can think of is SQL Server is converting the input to a FLOAT before trying to round it.  So it's changing 1.3278100 to something like 1.32780999999999999999 and leaving the 1.3278200 as 1.3278200.

Comment: yes that's right. and if the float is slightly below theactual decimal value, truncating it reduces it to the next lower value...

Comment: If you scroll down to the examples in the link Charles provided, they talk about this exact behavior.  Not that they actually explain it...

Comment: Andrew, where?  I don't see anything relating to truncation problems with FLOAT's using ROUND().

Comment: The first entry under Examples is `A. Using ROUND and estimates`.  They state:  **The following example shows two expressions that demonstrate by using ROUND the last digit is always an estimate.**

Comment: That example doesn't use the 3rd parameter relating to truncation, it's an example for rounding up if the last digit is 5 or more.  Using ROUND() with DECIMAL's doesn't strip off the 0's off the ends.  I'm assuming that's what they're referring to.  Still say the ROUND() function is doing something weird with FLOAT's.  It's best to convert them to DECIMAL before trying to ROUND().

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROUND(@var,6)` instead of `ROUND(@var,6,1)`. There is a 3rd optional parameter in the `ROUND()` function and it looks like you don't need it here.

Comment: I do need it, they want the values truncated, not rounded.  Some of the FLOAT's have more than 6 digits.

For example, they want 1.3278839999999 truncated to 1.327883, not 1.327884

Comment: Oh I see, I caught your question before the edit it looks like

Comment: No, just I wasn't clear that they wanted the numbers truncated, and not rounded. :)